# Calculating the nth totative of a large primorial

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function, coprime, primorial

For finding the $n$th prime (or the number of primes less than a number), there are results for large numbers; I was wondering if something similar for the totatives of a primorial number is possible (where a totative is a number less than $n$ and coprime with $n$)(i.e. given a similarly large primorial number, find the $n$th totative of the primorial or find the number of totatives of a primorial number that are less than $n$).  I am thinking of numbers with size of  $10^{20}$ since that is possible for the $n$th prime algorithms.

**Note:** The primorial $p_k$# is defined as the product of the first $k$ primes (in mathematical notation, this can be written as $p_k$# $= \prod_{r=1}^{n}p_k$).

Comment: For totative, I meant numbers less than n that are coprime to n.

Comment: What is primorial ?

Comment: This boils down to count the $y$-rough numbers (numbers having no prime factor $p\le y$) below $x$ , for which only approximations can be determined efficiently with our current knowledge.